# Each base edge and apex "form/forms" a trangle

Tags: numbers

> Each base edge and apex **form** a triangle. ([Wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)))

When there is the determiner, *each*, doesn't the subject become singular? I mean the verb, *form*, needs to be changed to ‘*forms*’. Is it mistyped or is it right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It should be '_forms_.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably he wanted to say is *"Each edge", base and apex form a triangle* which is a correct statement, both technically and in English.

If you want to keep it the way it is, consider *"each base"* a single word and then it is still a correct English statement. But probably he should've reordered it better. (*apex, edge and each base*?)

The way it is written now, your concern is perfectly right and it should be '*forms*' here.

Comment: Yes, I got it. [Each base] and [(the) apex] form a triangle, is what the writer intended to say, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, writer considered [each base] together and then the rest of it.